# How to return jsonResponse for single object model filtered on Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I have single object filtered as below.

```
backTest= BackTest.objects.first()
```

I would like to return this object as jsonResponse.

```
data = dumps(backTest)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

I got error message as below.

```
Object of type BackTest is not JSON serializable
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Django 1.7+,use this :

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
backTest= BackTest.objects.first()
return JsonResponse({'backtest':backTest})
```